# How to get TLS connection bytes from a client connecting to the server?

Tags: tcp, rust

I am working a project to peek the connection and get the raw byte data of the client hello from a client attempting to connect to a rust tcp server. However, I'm a little lost as to how to approach this, especially being a beginner of rust.

So far, this is what I have, but it seems like I am misunderstanding what data is sent by the tcpstream. How can I access the client hello data?

```
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8000").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 1024];
                let len = stream.peek(&mut buf).expect("peek failed");
            }
            Err(e) => { /* connection failed */ }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The data should be inside `buf[0..len]`

Comment: @Jmb the data i'm trying to get is client hello from the handshake. I don't think it is in &buf.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about: there is no "hello" in a TCP handshake, so any "hello" has to come from a higher-level protocol, and that _will_ be in `buf`.